# Trying to filter by specific value (ID) retrieves multiple results

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make an Angular filter that filters down to specific ID.

Let's say I'm trying to filter the line items to 'ID:'8. It will filter down to that ID, but also show in the results 'ID:18'. It's not being specific to the value I'm filtering, but returning all values that have 8.

I'm trying to get it to be specific to 'ID:'8.

Here's my html:

```
  <ion-item class="item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="item in recipes | filter: { id:whichrecipe }">
        <img ng-src="{{item.image}}.jpg" alt="{{item.name}} Image">
            <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
            <p>{{item.description}}</p>
  </ion-item>
```

Here's my controller:

```
.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', 
function($scope, $http, $state) {
    $http.get('js/recipes.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.recipes = data;
    $scope.whichrecipe=$state.params.id;
    $scope.data = {showDelete: false, showReorder: false}    

        $scope.toggleStar = function(item) {
            item.star =  !item.star;
        }

        $scope.moveItem = function(item, fromIndex, toIndex) {
        $scope.recipes.splice(fromIndex, 1);
        $scope.recipes.splice(toIndex, 0, item);
    };

    });
}]);
```

I tried filter: { id:whichrecipe }:true which returned 0 results.

Comment: Does adding `toString()` to `whichrecipe` in `{ id:whichrecipe }` do anything?  I'm not even sure if that's legal to be honest.  Also, if you're adding a comparator I think it's supposed to be `{id : whichrecipe : true}` instead of `{id : whichrecipe} : true`.  [Check this out](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

Comment: Thanks for the response. It looks like neither of those work for me. I did the expression ng-repeat="item in recipes | filter : id : true } as well as ng-repeat="item in recipes | filter : id : whichrecipes : true }.

Comment: Well, I looked at angular documentation and did an example in codepen. Check this out: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvMdKK?editors=101. Just check the "Equality" box and you should see it working.